# node.js server error - .get()

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, nosql

I have trying to run the server using locallydb and on the server side, I have got this code here... The login file is in the main directory.
 and I get the following error: If any one can help...

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\projectApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:196
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\projectApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:196:15)
    at EventEmitter.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\projectApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:481:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\projectApp\server.js:7:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (node.js:348:7)
```

**Server.js**

```
 var express = require('express');
    var login = require('./login');
    express()
        .set('view engine', 'ejs')
        .use(express.static('./public'))
        .use(login.routes)
        .get('*',login.required, function (req, res) {
            res.render('index',{
                user: login.safe(req.user)
            });
            }).listen(3000);
```

**Login.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');


var LocallyDB = require('locallydb');
var db = new LocallyDB('./.data');
var users = db.collection('users');

var crypto = require('crypto');

function hash (password) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha512').update(password).digest('hex');
}

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    var user = users.where({ username: username, passwordHash: hash(password) }).items[0];

    if (user) {
        done(null, user);
    } else {
        done(null, false);
    }
}));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.cid);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (cid, done) {
    done(null, users.get(cid));
});


var router = require('express').Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Login Page
router.use(bodyParser.json()); // API
router.use(require('cookie-parser')());
router.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'p7r6uktdhmcgvho8o6e5ysrhxmcgjfkot7r6elu5dtjt7lirfyj',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());

router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});

router.post('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
    if (users.where({ username: req.body.username }).items.length === 0) {
        var user = {
            fullname: req.body.fullname,
            email: req.body.email,
            username: req.body.username,
            passwordHash: hash(req.body.password),
            following: []
        };

        var userId = users.insert(user);

        req.login(users.get(userId), function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));

exports.routes = router;
```

Comment: have you exported `login.required` from './login'?

Comment: Yes, the login.js file is created in the same directory as this code file(server.js)

Comment: Can you post the content of that file, please? It appears you don't have a `module.exports.required = function () {...}` in that file, at least from what I can tell by the stack trace, as something in the `.get` method is undefined, and it can't be the string or function you passed in.

Comment: Which file do you need?